# browser does not fill the background properly with repeat-x

Tags: css

in the header menu i am using an image with repeat-x property. it works perfectly in full screen however in low resolution i.e in 1024X768 and 800X600 screen it leaves some margin. it leaves the margin when a horizontal scroll takes place. how do i make sure even if horizontal scroll exist the repeat-x property should cover the area of the scroll.  is there any css property for this?

the css for this i am using is.

```
#header {
    height: 111px;
    background: url('../img/header-bg.jpg') repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
}
```

let me know if you want more code ill host it in jsfiddle. thank you.

i have hosted my site in http://iarmar.com/test/bn just in case you want to test.

Comment: Which browsers are you testing this with? Is the behaviour the same across different browsers?

Comment: yes it is the case with every browser check out the site at http://iarmar.com/test/bn try resizing the window and the scroll area does not fill the image which has repeat-x property. i.e the top menu

Comment: Seems to work perfectly for me in Chrome. (latest update)

Comment: @kyle i tested in chrome, and the problem exist. i tested it using many tools too. check out for the white space and margin when you resize the window to small. the the horizontal scroll on right position will have the blank margin

Comment: Where does this margin appear? I can't see what you're referring to.

Comment: well resize the browser to half the size, and then the browser will display the horizontal scroll. then scroll to right side and check the header or top menu, the brown menu i am talking about or else check the website again in 1024X768 resolution

Comment: @kyle it is actually not the problem, i tested it with every website and almost everyone display the same way. and i have seen some website before which dynamically flow the background as and when you resize. i want it that way. the repeat-x property should cover the entire area even if the browser detects the website as high resolution and display the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: @Ibrahim, it seems to work fine as is on Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu 10.04. Have you checked to make sure that you're not loading css from the browser's cache?

Comment: Aha, I see. This is because your header is at a fixed width, set a `min-width` or `100%`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `min-width: 1040px;` to your `#header`

Comment: Aha, got there just before me! :)

Answer (score 1):

As expalined in my comment (and by Jeaffrey), set your `#header` with a `min-width` or use `100%`.

Comment: i hope i did not make question too complicated for you to understand Kyle. :)

Comment: No, I think I just misread, I did that a few times today, maybe I should go home :D

Answer (score 0):

See this www.viralment.com oh its says 30 at least
try using these:

```
background-image: url("gradient_bg.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```